# How to setup the proper MEF configuration?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, mef

I have a class library with one class called `IConfiguration` which is an interface with just one property.

I have a class library called `TexasConfiguration` which implements `IConfiguration` and another class library called `FloridaConfiguration` which implements `IConfiguration`.

I have decorated `TexasConfiguration` and `FloridaConfiguration` with `[Export(typeof(IConfiguration)]`

I have another class which is  sealed class called `ConfigurationSystem` and it contains a private constructor defined as `private ConfigurationSystem() {}`

There are few issues I have.  Generally speaking, where should I put the MEF stuff to set it up.  Currently, I have put a static method in `ConfigurationSystem` along with the following declaration:

```
[Import(typeof(IConfiguration)]
IConfiguration configuration {get; set;}
```

In the above, it tells me that `configuration` is unused. Is this normal in this case.

I also created a static method in `ConfigurationSystem`,but if I make it static, I can't pass `this` to it, I have to pass `typeof(ConfigurationSystem)` to it:

```
public static void SetupConfiguration()
    {
        using (DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@"c:\\developement\source\configuration"))
        {
            CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            container.ComposeParts(typeof(ConfigurationSystem));
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
ConfigurationSystem.SetupConfiguration();
```

but I can't do this unless the method is declared static. In a nutshell, when the application is started, it calls a static method `Initialize` where I want to call my `SetupConfiguration` and assign the appropriate configuration object to `IConfiguration`.

Answer (score 1):

MEF is designed to work with object instances, not with static classes. The call to `container.ComposeParts(typeof(ConfigurationSystem))` will do absolutely nothing, since what you're basically asking here is for MEF to compose the parts for the `Type` object you passed to it, which is obviously not what you wanted.

There is a simple solution though that won't cause you to change your application's architecture too much. You could make your `ConfigurationSystem` class a singleton, and then you'll be able to call `container.ComposeParts(this)` and get your parts.

Comment: The problem is that `ConfigurationSystem` was not written by mean and it is marked sealed, so should I move the MEF Setup Code somewhere else outside `ConfigurationSystem`?

Comment: I use a Bootstrap class that can be a singleton which performs all of the MEF composition work.

Comment: @Xaisoft It's fairly hard to understand from your question that you can't modify `ConfigurationSystem`. If the `Import` definition is in `ConfigurationSystem`, and it must remain static, then you can't have MEF set that value for you. But if that's the case, why was it written with an `Import` in the first place?

Comment: @AdiLester - It wasn't. I am looking for a place to put MEF and this happens to a place were the app is initialized.